# Refactoring tool

Tags: .net, refactoring, resharper, recommendation-engine

I am using several months ReSharper 4.5 It's very powerfull tool but use a lot of system resources and VS working very slow with it. With which tool I can replace Resharper with the same functionality. Which refactoring tool do you use?

Comment: Have you tried to contact JetBrain's support? ReSharper does have overhead, but in my case, it is not that terrible (VS is completely usable)

Comment: Polaris, if you need help with ReSharper, please feel free to contact me and we can see if we can solve your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love [Code Rush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/)  Best part is it is free.  There is a paid version.

> CodeRush Xpress includes over 50
>   refactorings, and nearly all work in
>   both C# and Visual Basic. A few
>   refactorings are available in only a
>   single language due to features of
>   that particular language. All
>   refactorings can be split into the
>   following groups:
>
> Changing Signatures Conditionals
>   Declaration and Initialization
>   Expressions Lambda Expressions and
>   Anonymous Methods Loops and Blocks
>   Properties and Fields
>   Moving/Extracting Methods Resource
>   Files and Strings Types Visibility

Comment: I just installed Code Rushe Express v 10. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

There's [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/).